# Why can't VPN extensions filter everything in the browser?

Tags: vpn, browser-extensions

For example, when I'm using one of this extensions, such as ZenMate or Browsec, I'm not able to watch video streamings. Or another thing that happened is my internet provider detecting me going on a blacklisted website after having clicked on a link to it (in an email received on Temp-mail.org), while using the extension! Shouldn't everything which is in the browser be crypted? Why does the provider still see which website I'm visiting? Curious (to me at least) is that the provider could only detect it if I clicked on the link, while if I copy-pasted the URL manually in the address bar no detection happened.